# How to open a specified ssh host and get connect result or error message in my extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

In my extensionm, I want to call remote-ssh api to open a remote host in a new window, and then get the connect result and error message, and then I want to parse the error message and suggest some fixes to users.
First I tried this method：

```
   vscode.commands.executeCommand('opensshremotes.openEmptyWindow')
```

But this method requires the user to select a host instead of directly opening the specified host，which is not what I need.
Then I used a method which was found in an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/86196) (But I didn't find any API documentation about this) :

```
   const response = vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.newWindow", {
       remoteAuthority: `ssh-remote+${sshName}`
   }
```

This method can open the specified host, but I can not get result of it.
So I want to ask:

1. What is the recommended way to open a specified ssh host by code?
2. How to get the error message, such as connect timeout or permission denied ?

Thank you~

Comment: The response is like this:  Promise {[[PromiseState]]: 'pending', [[PromiseResult]]: undefined, Symbol(async_id_symbol): 2757, Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol): 2750, Symbol(destroyed): {…}} .